# PostgreSQL with LabVIEW psql.exe password request (WINDOWS)

Tags: postgresql, psql, labview

I am working with LabVIEW (2016) to insert data into a PostgreSQL (9.6) database. I followed an example from NI:

https://decibel.ni.com/content/docs/DOC-30308#comment-51678.

Here is also a screen shot of the LabVIEW block diagram [image: Here is a screen shot of the LabVIEW block diagram]

PROBLEM:

- **Password request from the psql.exe** file when executing LabVIEW code
- Type password, psql.exe closes and opens again
- **SELECT query works without while loop** (password accepted once) but insert and clear does not without the loop condition

What I've tried...

1. Created a **pgpass.conf** file in a postgresql folder in %AppData% in the following format:- *hostname:port:database:username:password*, where lisam is the database, postgres is the user.

Host name as localhost '127.0.0.1' - password still requested.

```
    127.0.0.1:5432:lisam:postgres:password
```

Host name as 'localhost' - psql.exe flashes continously and LabVIEW crashes.

```
    localhost:5432:database:username:password
```

Host name as database client address '::1' - password loop with the psql.exe.

```
    ::1:5432:database:username:password
```

Host name to '*' -

```
    *:5432:lisam:postgres:password
```

Able to:

- Access the database through the cmd WITHOUT password

  ```
  C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/psql -c "SELECT * FROM demo1" lisam postgres
  ```

Problems:

- Execution in Labview - psql.exe flashes continuously and the program crashes.
- Accessing database through psql.exe directly - password requested and ERROR received
      "psql: FATAL: password authentication failed for user C:\Program Files"

2.Changed the **authentication method in pg_hba.conf** to trust for:

- localhost (127.0.0.1)- a password is still requested.
- 127.0.0.1 AND ::1 - Can access the database on psql without a password, but the psql.exe LabVIEW completely crashes.

  3. I tried **adding the host and port** to the code

     C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/psql -c "%s" -h 127.0.0.1 -p 5432 lisam postgres

And the psql.exe flashes continously and won't abort.

4. Running a different example where I generate a sine signal and insert the data into the database - it works. The password only breaksdown in a while loop.

I'm pretty stuck for ideas now so any help will be extremely appreciated.

Lisa

---

**Info:**

- database name: lisam
- database user: postgres

IPv4 local connections-

```
    host all all 127.0.0.1/32 md5
```

IPv6 local connections-

```
    host all all ::1/128 md5

    DB:lisam Client Address ::1
    psql Client address 127.0.0.1
```

---

Comment: I typed them into the SQL shell (psql) through PgAdmin.

Comment: I tried to find pgpass.conf in the %appdata% folder, but as I mentioned above I cannot even locate a postgresql folder in %appdata%.

Comment: I created the pgpass.conf file in the format:
localhost:port:database:username:password and getting "psql FATAL: password authentication failed for user"

Comment: When I executed psql manually the password box popped up, I typed in the password I set in pgpass.conf and the box disappeared. The same error flashed before it closed

Comment: I don't know if it makes a difference but it says authentication failed for user "Lisa Marfell" which is my computer name but my username for postgresql is "lisam". I did try to change my PC username to lisam too but it seems it hasn't changed consistently. I tried using postgres as the user too but that didn't work.

Comment: The line `C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/psql -c "%s" lisam` is missing the database (or the username) you want to connect to. As it stands that is the _databasename_. To pass both you need to use `psql dbname username` [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html) and shown when you run `psql --help`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks! Looking at the pgadmin dashboard my database the user of my database is actually postgres. So I tried as you suggested         "C:/Program Files/PostgreSQL/9.6/bin/psql -c "%s" lisa postgres" and now the password request states: "Password for user postgres" where before it just said "Password". But the password still doesn't work. I tried executing psql manually again and the username is still my windows machine username.

Comment: The order is `dbname username` [as documented in the manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html). You specified the username first, then the database

Comment: lisam is the dbname and postgres is the username. The order is correct

Comment: The only thing I can think of is that this labview thing calls psql incorrectly somehow. It sounds as if it doesn't actually pass the username. You could try to set the [environment variables](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/310519) `PGDATABASE` and `PGUSER` so that that information does not need to be supplied on the command line. Or put everything in a batch file and let labview call that batch file

Comment: I think you are right in that psql is called incorrectly. I tried to run the command in the cmd in the psql directory: "psql -c SELECT * from demo1 lisam postgres" and it says "psql is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file."

Comment: Then you need to add the directory to the global `PATH`

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name thanks so much for your time. I set the path in the environment variable for psql. Now I can get the psql executable working in the cmd, but still no luck with LabVIEW.

Comment: Bear in mind that the NI example refers to NI Real-Time Linux running on a cRIO device - what platform and OS are you using?

Comment: @nekomatic I am using Windows 10. I don't currently have access to the cRIO, so I was attempting the tutorial without connecting the cRIO to PostgreSQL. So I just created the database on PostgreSQL and followed the block diagram. Could this be the issue for the password failure?

Comment: I don't know but it seems likely that something may have to be done differently for the two systems. Once you've got the command(s) you want working from the Windows command line I can only suggest playing around with System Exec to make sure it's passing your command correctly (maybe try with some other Windows commands or your own batch file?) and if you're still stuck pursue it on the NI forums, LAVA forums or if all else fails the info-labview mailing list. Good luck!

Comment: @nekomatic thanks for your help. I managed to get the SELECT query working without the while loop. Just trying to get the INSERT INTO working now